# Exclude Dependency from Webpack from create-react-app project

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap

I have the following dependencies for my project.

```
"dependencies": {
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.28.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
```

I created my project using the nice boilerplate command, `create-react-app my-app`.

I'm now having an issue where I need to tell WebPack (which I found out React uses) to exclude the dependency of jQuery so I can get [React Slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-slider) working.

Problem is the webpack config is part of the node modules.  If I modify anything in there it won't reflect for any users downloading my project.  There should be a way to override the default webpack settings but I'm not sure how to do this?

I found this [project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/configurable-react-scripts) which might do what I need but not sure.

The instructions say I need to add this to the webpack config.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
         "jquery": path.join(__dirname, "./jquery-stub.js");
    }
}
```

**How do I do this given I don't have access to Webpack directly?**

Comment: Have a look to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183773/Create-React-App-Customize-Webpack-Config-Without). May it help!

Comment: Interesting you are on right track.  I might have to look into the eject feature first that comes with it

Comment: Looks like eject was what I needed, although it sucks to have to eject.

Answer (score 7):

There is a module called [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) that helps to extend the webpack config that comes with create react app without ejecting. An example of how you might add the resolve section looks like this

`$ npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired`

You would need to create a file in the same directory as your `package.json`

```
/* config-overrides.js */
let path = require('path')


function rewireJquery(config, env) {
  config.resolve = {
    alias: {
         "jquery": path.join(__dirname, "./jquery-stub.js");
    }
  };
  return config;
}
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...
  // config = rewirePreact(config, env);
  if (env === "production") {
    config = rewireJquery(config, env);
  }
  return config;
};
```

you would need to install the module `react-app-rewired` and configure your `package.json` to include the following

```
 /* package.json */

  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom"
}
```

With the above, you can extend the `webpack` config without ejecting.

Comment: This is pretty useful :).  I will give this a try for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[@gbozee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783192/3773658) worked for me with a small change in the `rewireJquery` function

```
/* config-overrides.js */
let path = require('path')


function rewireJquery(config, env) {
  config.resolve = config.resolve || {};
  config.resolve.alias = config.resolve.alias || {};
  config.resolve.alias.jquery = path.join(__dirname, "./stubs/jquery-stub.js");
  return config;
}
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...
  // config = rewirePreact(config, env);
  if (env === "production") {
    config = rewireJquery(config, env);
  }
  return config;
};
```

You also need to remove the `env === "production"` condition for this to work on local.

**Please note, entire credit goes to [@gbozee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783192/3773658).**